# Local settings not found : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'account'

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I'm getting error in cmd:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'account'

Below is my code in which i am facing some issue. any change needed in command or the code?

[image]

```
import account.form
from django import forms
 
class SignupForm(account.forms.SignupForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        del self.fields["username"]


class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution to this issue, most probably if you are facing similar issue you need to create a new module and install python package file for django user account : `pip install django-user-accounts`

Answer (score 1):

The import is incorrect. `account` belongs to the `allauth` package which you have not imported. Try using this

```py
from allauth import account
from django import forms
 
class SignupForm(account.forms.SignupForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        del self.fields["username"]


class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()
```

Comment: Still it shows the same error. Even after making necessary changes.

Comment: Please provide the complete error in **text** format. You can update your question with it.